# Dcraw bit depth of 14 bit in output 16 bit tiff

Tags: dcraw

How is it possible to convert a 14-bit raw (Nikon D7000 NEF) to 16-bit tiff preserving the bit depth (ie. max of 16383) and not getting a max of 65535.
I'm using

```
dcraw -T -4 input.NEF
```